# How to open a code block using emacs org-mode in a specific window

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When working with `org-mode` I would like to edit a code block in a specific window.

While `org-mode` does allow some customization with respect to which window a code block will open in, it is quite limited. The four options currently available for the `org-src-window-setup` variable include `current-window`, `other-window`, `other-frame`, and `reorganize-frame`. However, these do not accomplish my goal.

I would like to either be able to specify a specific window and/or use `windmove-right`, for instance, from the `windmove` package. At the moment, I can only specify one of the four options above. Also, `other-window`, does not actually go to the other window. Instead it opens a vertical split and creates a new window. At least in my setup.

Is there a way to alter what options the `org-src-window-setup` variable accepts? Or perhaps there is another solution?

Comment: you might have to do some emacs-lisp hacking to get this working the way you want it (that's my guess based on the description)

Comment: Please, test what `M-x display-buffer bufferOfYourChoice` does with your setup.

Comment: Please, test it also with prefix-arg `C-u M-x display-buffer bufferOfYourChoice`. Can you reproduce your problems on this basis?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for:

```
C-c '
```

which opens a new window for code editing. You insert the code in your file by saving the buffer

```
C-x C-s
```

or by closing the code buffer with

```
C-c '
```

For code block there is a shortcut (yasnipet)

```
<s [tab]
```

More: [orgmode documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/Editing-source-code.html)